# How to automatically import field value of polygon to point field based on spatial query?

Tags: qgis

I have two layers, points and polygons. Point layer is empty. When I add new point feature I want to update it's field by values of polygon field if new point is within polygon. I need solution in QGIS.

How can I do this?